# std::thread segfault with null native thread

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdthread

Can you help me understand why this code is giving me a segfault as below? Could there be a problem in the way I create threads? I'm having difficulty understanding the issue. Please note that I have simplified the question as much as possible - I am compiling the code with -O3 and getting a zero page error, but the code is valid.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <new>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

class temp {
private:
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::vector<std::string> m_tokens;

public:
    temp()
    {
        m_thread = std::thread(&temp::run, this);
    }

    void run()
    {
        while (1) {
            std::string token;
            std::cin >> token;

            if (std::ranges::find(m_tokens, token) != m_tokens.end()) {
                std::cout << "duplicate token" << token << "\n";
                continue;
            }

            m_tokens.push_back(token);

            std::cout << token << " added\n";
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    temp t;
    
    while (1)
        ;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
ThreadSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==19246==ERROR: ThreadSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f81d5f98880 bp 0x7b0800000020 sp 0x7f81d30bf298 T19247)
==19246==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
==19246==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 __tsan_func_entry <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x9e880)
    #1 std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (temp::*)(), temp*> > >::_M_run() /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (trading+0x41e3a3)
    #2 execute_native_thread_routine <null> (trading+0x437ab3)
    #3 start_thread <null> (libpthread.so.0+0x7ea4)
    #4 clone <null> (libc.so.6+0xfeb0c)

ThreadSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: SEGV (/lib64/libtsan.so.0+0x9e880) in __tsan_func_entry
==19246==ABORTING
```

How is it possible that the code runs without any issues when I run it directly, but gives a segfault error when run as a thread?

Comment: `while (1) ;` is undefined behaviour - check this has not been removed by the compiler.

Comment: Doing input in a new thread is not really a good idea. And this whole program, as it is shown to us, is not a good candidate for using threads.

Comment: _"but the code is valid"_  This code has guaranteed Undefined Behavior, which you should not consider "valid" if you have expectations regarding this program's behavior.

Comment: changed the code, now it joins but still the same error is here

Comment: After getting valid answer(s), it is not considered good form to change your question to make existing answers incorrect.

Comment: @DrewDormann None of the answers were valid as they did not focus on the question itself

Comment: What OS, compiler, standard library, etc. are you testing this with? What is the input you are using?

Comment: Is this the Real Code that is producing this segfault?  I'm [having great difficulty](https://godbolt.org/z/vYcbcvnqn) finding any compiler that can compile this exact code.

Comment: You are missing `-pthread` in the compiler invocation. [...] Nevermind, that's not the linking step. Do you use `-pthread` in the linking step?

Comment: Don't edit the code and change the question after you have got an answer to your original question. You can delete the wrong question and try to ask again.

Comment: Given the two edits of the question, and the concern of the cout etc in the thread, what happens when you remove the IO from the thread (replace with some fixed token value)? Does it give the same error?

Answer (score 3):

You must call `.join()` on the `std::thread` object in the main thread (e.g. in `temp`'s destructor) in order to have the main thread wait until the thread managed by the `std::thread` exits.

Infinite loops are no replacement for that and infinite loops without observable side effect have undefined behavior in C++. Compilers do optimize under the assumption that they can never be executed, sometimes going as far as compiling complete nonsense for functions containing them (e.g. Clang) or simply removing them.

Comment: I have simplified the question as much as possible - I am compiling the code with -O3 and getting a zero page error, but the code is valid

Comment: @avatli The code you are showing us is not valid.